# Html form error

Tags: html, forms

This is my form but when I click submit button it shows some error in the form. I am not able to identify it.

```
 <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="email.php">
            <div class="row" style=" font-weight: lighter;">

                <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#000;">
                    First Name:<br><br><input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#000;">
                    Last Name:<br><br><input type="text" name="last" value="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#000;">
                    Email:<br><br><input type="text" name="email" value="">
                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row" style=" font-weight: lighter;">

                <div class="col-lg-8" style="color:#000;">
                    Your Interest*<br><br><select name="interest">
                    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>

                </select>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#000;">
                    Phone*<br><br><input type="text" name="phone" value="">
                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row" style=" font-weight: lighter;">

                <div class="col-lg-8" style="color:#000;">
                    Module Categoey*<br><br><select name="module">
                    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <option value="Accessory">Accessory</option>
                <option value="Audio">Audio</option>

                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4" style="color:#000;">
                    Role*<br><br><select name="role">
                    <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
                <option value="Company">Company</option>

                </select>

                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row" style=" font-weight: lighter;">

                <div class="col-lg-12" style="color:#000;">
                    Tell us about yourself:<br><br><textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row" style=" font-weight: lighter;">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="color:#000;">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">I accept the Terms and Conditions and acknowledge that my information will be used in accordance with Google Privacy Policy*</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="color:#000;">
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " style="color:#000;" aria-label="Play">Submit<i></i></button>-->
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " style="color:#000;"  value="Submit">
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Help to identify the error. it shows "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.

Please go back and fix these errors. "

This is my php file email.php

```
            <?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['firstname'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['interest'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['module'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'pravakar@mrwebsiter.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die; 
    ?>
```

Comment: That error sounds like it is generated by `email.php`. You haven't show us the code for that.

Comment: Please read this: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have added my email.php file

Comment: So you've included the code now. What have you done to track down why you are getting the error message? You can see where it comes from. The function is only called from a couple of places. Debug it.

Answer (score 0):

See if you fields in the form match your conditions here:

```
if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) ||
   !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||
   !isset($_POST['email']) ||
   !isset($_POST['interest']) ||
   !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
   !isset($_POST['module']) ||
   !isset($_POST['role']) ||
   !isset($_POST['description'])) {
   died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}
```

You can make error message better if you test each field separately.

Comment: i have edited the php file and now i can get the email. But i want the success message of the form in the same page in the div alert section above form. But right now success message comes in email.php page

Comment: Put the php code of email.php in the same page as the form and action = same page or use session variables and redirect after success to your form page